# AjaxAnywhere not working after jdk upgrade

Tags: java, javascript, jsp-tags

Recently i upgraded my application java version from jdk 1.5 to 1.7. I am using ajaxanywhere as ajax thirdparty jar for ajax work. After upgrading jdk version, jar is not working properly. It is not updating referesh zone after ajax call.

url of ajaxanywhere http://ajaxanywhere.sourceforge.net/

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

that project is discontinued. Why don't you use my fork which allows you to do everything without writing a single line of Javascript :-)

- http://www.ajaxanywhere.com/

Comment: Is there any use of AjaxAnywhere in 2020?

Comment: Only if you use server side rendering via JSPs or GSPs, which is a paradigm in obvious decline.